# Orthogonality of Bessel function $\int_0^bxJ_a(\ell x)J_a(\ell' x)=0$ for $\ell\neq\ell'$

Tags: differential-equations, bessel-functions, sturm-liouville-theory

How do I show the above relation with Sturm-Liouville theory (assume the usual boundary conditions for the identity)? Here is what I have tried: if we start with
$$
\big(xJ_a'(\ell x)
\big)'+\left(\ell^2-\frac{a^2}{x}\right)J_a(\ell x)=0
$$
and
$$
\big(xJ_a'(\ell' x)
\big)'+\left(\ell'^2-\frac{a^2}{x}\right)J_a(\ell' x)=0
$$
and multiply the top expression by $xJ_a(\ell' x)$ and bottom by $xJ_a(\ell' x)$ and subtract the two equations,
$$
x\big(xJ_a'(\ell x)
\big)'-x\big(xJ_a'(\ell' x)
\big)'+x(\ell^2-\ell'^2)J_a(\ell x)J_a(\ell' x)=0.
$$
Then by rearrangement and integration over $[0, a]$ my answer is wrong. To be explicit, I get:
$$
\int_0^axJ_m(\ell x)J_m(\ell'x)=\frac{a\big(J_m'(\ell a)J_m(\ell' a)-J_m'(\ell' a)J_m(\ell a)\big)}{\ell^2-\ell'^2}
$$
which is just barely wrong--- the correct result is
$$
\int_0^axJ_m(\ell x)J_m(\ell'x)=\frac{a\big(\ell J_m'(\ell a)J_m(\ell' a)-\ell'J_m'(\ell' a)J_m(\ell a)\big)}{\ell^2-\ell'^2}
$$
which is zero (by the usual boundary conditions)

What am I doing wrong? Also-- is the reason we choose to multiply by $x\,\times$ the bessel function because of the "weight function" present in the Sturm–Liouville form of the Bessel function? Is this to ensure that our functions vanish at certain points?

Thank you!

Comment: @AlapanDas Yes I changed $q$ to $a$. However changing $a$ to $m$ is unnecessary. I just used it as a dummy variable.

Comment: @AlapanDas when you say "that" what do you mean?

Comment: Ahhh sorry that is a typo.

Comment: The Bessel equation is $(xJ'_a(lx))'+(l^2x-\frac{q^2}{x})J_a(lx)=0$.

Comment: Eigenfunctions of a self-adjoint operator are orthogonal, so if you set it up correctly, you don't need any calculation.

Comment: @AlapanDas $x^2y''+xy'+(\ell^2x^2-a^2)y=0$. Replace $y$ by $J_a(\ell x).$

Comment: @ChristianRemling yes that is what I am asking--- how can I set it up? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For, $bl$ and $bl'$ being distinct zeroes of Bessel function , we have
$(xJ_a(lx)')'+(l^2x-q^2/X)J_a(lx)=0$ and

$(xJ_a(l'x)')'+(l'^2x-q^2/X)J_a(l'x)=0$ .

Multiplying first with $J_a(l'x)$ and second with $J_a(l'x)$ and then subsratcting second from first ,

$-[J_a(l'x)(xJ_a(l'x))'-J_a(lx)(xJ'_a(l'x))']=x(l^2-l'^2)xJ_a(lx)J_a(l'x)$

Now, $J_a(l'x)(xJ'_a(l'x))'-J_a(lx)(xJ'_a(l'x))'=\frac{d}{dx}(xJ_a(l'x)J'_a(lx)-xJ_a(lx)J'_a(l'x)$

Hence, $\int_{0}^{b} xJ_a(lx)J_a(l'x)=\frac{bJ_a(l'b)J'_a(lb)-bJ_a(lb)J'_a(l'b)}{l^2-l'^2}$.

Comment: I get the same thing, but according to https://www.math.usm.edu/lambers/mat415/lecture15.pdf, it is wrong. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: See, what I have meant by $J'_a(lx)$ say, $A(x)$ is $\frac{d J_a(lx)}{dx}$. But what is meant there by $J'_a(lx)$ say, $B(x)$ is $\frac{d J_a'(t)}{dt}$ at $t=lx$. And $B(x)=lA(x)$. That's why those terms are appearing.

Comment: So they are appearing from the boundary conditions?

Comment: Or is this just the chain rule?

Comment: Yes, it's just due to chain rule.

Comment: Ok I got it now. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If $l \ne m$, then
$$
\int_{0}^{b}\!x{{\rm J}_{a}\left(lx\right)}{{\rm J}_{a}\left(mx\right)
}\,{\rm d}x={\frac {b \big( {{\rm J}_{a+1}\left(lb\right)}\;{{\rm J}_{a
}\left(mb\right)}\;l-{{\rm J}_{a+1}\left(mb\right)}\;{{\rm J}_{a}\left(lb
\right)}\;m \big) }{{l}^{2}-{m}^{2}}}
$$

Assume $l,m$ are zeros of $J_a$ and $b=1$.  Then we get the value $0$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Gerald. I should have been more specific when I said "for the usual conditions." This identity follows from assuming $\ell$ and $\ell'$ are the zeros of the Bessel function.